Wireguard and duckduckgo Issue
I have some problems with wireguard client on linux. When I turn a connection to vpn on, I can't reach duckduckgo.com in my browser (both Chromium and Firefox). But if i ping the domain in terminal I get normal response. Same configration but on my Android phone works perfectly fine. In vpn configuration on server I use 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 as DNS. What migh cause that?

Please add the full outputs of nft list ruleset, iptables-save, cat /etc/resolv.conf and resolvectl that are captured after turn a connection to vpn on. Preferably you should include your wg client config file as well. (Make sure you redact the keys before you submit the edit. They can still be seen in the history if you remove them by editing again.) (Btw I don't suppose you have any proxy settings in the browsers? Also is duckduckgo.com like just an example, or is it like you are only having problem with this specific site?)
